# SQL query to check availability on an event table

Tags: sql, calendar, temp-tables

I have a table of events with the columns `Room Number` and `Date`

I want to check availability in a certain room so I tried creating a temp calendar table just to compare, but I know I'm doing something wrong with my left join so I need some pointers to help me achieve my goal: only show the dates where there is no event in the specific room.

This is my query so far:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#calendarTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #calendarTable;
    GO

CREATE TABLE #calendarTable (
    "DayID" INT
    ,"DayDate" DATE
    ,PRIMARY KEY (DayID)
    )

DECLARE @startDate AS DATE
DECLARE @baseDate DATE
    ,@offSet INT
    ,@numberOfLoops INT

SET @startDate = GETDATE() /*'20150101'*/
SET @baseDate =  @startDate
SET @offSet = 0
SET @numberOfLoops = DATEDIFF(DAY, @baseDate, DATEADD(MONTH, 24, @baseDate)) /*365*/

WHILE (@offSet < @numberOfLoops)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #calendarTable (
        "DayID"
        ,"DayDate"
        )
    SELECT (@offSet + 1)
        ,DATEADD(DAY, @offSet, @baseDate)

    SET @offSet = @offSet + 1
END

SELECT TOP (500)
DayDate
,a.Arrangement_Number
,a.Activity
,a.Room_Number
FROM #calendarTable 
left outer join [Events] as a ON DayDate = (convert(varchar(10), a.[Date],120))
where Room_Number = 53
order by DayDate asc
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results as per [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help.